# What is the proper way to use a QUdpSocket as a QIODevice?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, udp

The [Qt 4.8 documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qudpsocket.html) contains the following advice:

> If you want to use the standard QIODevice functions read(), readLine(), write(), etc., you must first connect the socket directly to a peer by calling connectToHost().

so I tried the following code:

```
udp.connectToHost(hostName, hostPort);   // connected
udp.bind(hostName, hostPort);
```

When I execute this code, Qt logs the following debug message:

> QNativeSocketEngine::bind() was not called in QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState

meaning that `bind` requires the socket to be in the unconnected state. So I tried the following:

```
udp.bind(hostName, hostPort);  // bound
udp.connectToHost(hostName, hostPort);
```

but it doesn't work either: the socket does not connect to the host, it is left in error state.

What is the correct way to configure a QUdpSocket in order to use it as a QIODevice?

Answer (score 4):

The method to first bind a socket to specific local address/port and then connect the socket to a specific foreign address/port should work. So the second code example was the right one.

```
udp.bind(hostName, hostPort);  // bound
udp.connectToHost(hostName, hostPort);
```

But this does not work in Qt for versions < 5.5.0 as the functions used inside on `connectToHost` always unbound the socket first and bind it again to a free local port of whatever address.

For details see [QTBUG-26538 - QUdpSocket: connectToHost() resets local port number specified by bind()](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26538).

If it is important that the UDP socket is bound to a specific local address/port on "connecting" (UDP is connectionless) to a specific foreign name/port for usage of reimplemented `QIODevice` methods, I can't provide no other workaround for this Qt bug for Qt versions < 5.5.0 than patching (very carefully) the sources of used Qt version using the code of the applied patches which can be seen on page of [Qt 5.5 commit message 102610](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/102610/).